# How to import libraries in Spark Notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-notebook, magellan

I'm having trouble importing `magellan-1.0.4-s_2.11` in spark notebook. I've downloaded the jar from https://spark-packages.org/package/harsha2010/magellan and have tried placing `SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages harsha2010:magellan:1.0.4-s_2.11` in the `Start of Customized Settings` section of the spark-notebook file of the bin folder.

Here are my imports

```
import magellan.{Point, Polygon, PolyLine}
import magellan.coord.NAD83
import org.apache.spark.sql.magellan.MagellanContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.magellan.dsl.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
```

And my errors...

```
<console>:71: error: object Point is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.magellan
       import magellan.{Point, Polygon, PolyLine}
              ^
<console>:72: error: object coord is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.magellan
       import magellan.coord.NAD83
                       ^
<console>:73: error: object MagellanContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.magellan
       import org.apache.spark.sql.magellan.MagellanContext
```

I then tried to import the new library like any other library by placing it into the `main script` like so:

```
$lib_dir/magellan-1.0.4-s_2.11.jar"
```

This didn't work and I'm left scratching my head wondering what I've done wrong. How do I import libraries such as magellan into spark notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Try evaluating something like

```
:dp "harsha2010" % "magellan" % "1.0.4-s_2.11"
```

It will load the library into Spark, allowing it to be `import`ed - assuming it can be obtained though the Maven repo. In my case it failed with a message:

```
failed to load 'harsha2010:magellan:jar:1.0.4-s_2.11 (runtime)' from ["Maven2 local (file:/home/dev/.m2/repository/, releases+snapshots) without authentication", "maven-central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, releases+snapshots) without authentication", "spark-packages (http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/, releases+snapshots) without authentication", "oss-sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/, releases+snapshots) without authentication"] into /tmp/spark-notebook/aether/b2c7d8c5-1f56-4460-ad39-24c4e93a9786
```

I think file was to big and connection was interrupted before whole file could be downloaded.

**Workaround**

So I downloaded the JAR manually from:

```
http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/harsha2010/magellan/1.0.4-s_2.11/
```

and copied it into the:

```
/tmp/spark-notebook/aether/b2c7d8c5-1f56-4460-ad39-24c4e93a9786/harsha2010/magellan/1.0.4-s_2.11
```

And then `:dp` command worked. Try Calling it first, and if it will fail copy JAR into the right path to make things work.

**Better solution**

I should investigate why download failed to fix it in the first place... or put that library in my local M2 repo. But that should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check this:

https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook/blob/master/docs/metadata.md#import-download-dependencies

and

https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook/blob/master/docs/metadata.md#add-spark-packages

I think the `:dp` magic command is depreciated, instead you should add your custom dependencies in the notebook metadata. You can go in the menu Edit > Edit notebook metadata, there add something like:

```
"customDeps": [
   "harsha2010 % magellan % 1.0.4-s_2.11"
]
```

Once done, you will need to restart the kernel, you can check in the browser console if the package is being downloaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, you should set or add the *`EXTRA_CLASSPATH`* environnent variable to point to your *`.jar`* file downloaded :
 `export EXTRA_CLASSPATH = </link/to/your.jar>` or `set EXTRA_CLASSPATH= </link/to/your.jar>` in wondows OS. [Here find the detailed solution](https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook/issues/702).